Finder not remembering a newly associated Default application for opening files?
I have already opened a .docx file using "Other", selected LibreOffice and Always open with.  However Finder is not remembering this - and also open on the terminal/command line is still opening .docx with the previously asssociated application (wps).
Here is what I had done (but it does not 'take'):

Why is Finder not remembering the new default application ?

Did you set it for all files or for just that file?

@MarcWilson. I'm not even aware of the capability not to set it for all files. In the screenshot dialog we see "Always open with". That applies to all files sharing the extension. What are you referring to actually?

You're choosing the application to always use for opening that particular docx file, not the default.  Setting that checkbox is the same as choosing a new application in the file's Get Info dialog.  The Change All button in Get Info changes it for all files.

Got it now. Care to make that an answer?
